# Dependency injection in base and derived classes

Tags: php, dependency-injection, base-class

I have an abstract base Controller class and all action controllers are derived from it.

Base Controller class at construction initializes View object. This View object is used by all action controllers. Each action controller have different dependencies (this is solved by using DI container).

The problem is that base Controller class also needs some dependencies (or parameters), 
for example, path to view folder. And the question is - where and how to pass parameters to base Controller class?

```
$dic = new Dic();

// Register core objects: request, response, config, db, ...

class View
{
    // Getters and setters
    // Render method
}

abstract class Controller
{
    private $view;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->view = new View;

        // FIXME: How / from where to get view path?
        // $this->view->setPath();
    }

    public function getView()
    {
        return $this->view;
    }
}

class Foo_Controller extends Controller
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct(Db $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function barAction()
    {
        $this->getView()->some_var = 'test';
    }
}

require_once 'controllers/Foo_Controller.php';

// Creates object with dependencies which are required in __construct()
$ctrl = $dic->create('Foo_Controller');

$ctrl->barAction();
```

Comment: private $view; why is $view private? When do you know which view path to load? Inside the action controller? Then this can be easily done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a basic example. Why is the $view private? Is there a good reason?

```
class View {
  protected $path;
  protected $data = array();

  function setPath($path = 'standard path') {
    $this->path = $path;
  }

  function __set($key, $value) {
    $this->data[$key] = $value;
  }

  function __get($key) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $this->data)) {
      return $this->data[$key];
    }
  }
}

abstract class Controller {
    private $view;

    public function __construct($path)
    {
       $this->view = new View;

       $this->view->setPath($path);
    }

    public function getView()
    {
        return $this->view;
    }
}

class Foo_Controller extends Controller {
    private $db;


    public function __construct(Db $db, $path)
    {
        // call the parent constructor.
        parent::__construct($path);
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function barAction()
    {
        $this->getView()->some_var = 'test';
    }

    public function getAction() {
      return $this->getView()->some_var;
    }
}

class DB {

}

$con = new DB;
$ctrl = new Foo_Controller($con, 'main');

$ctrl->barAction();
print $ctrl->getAction();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick ansver! The View is private so it can't be overridden from the outside, only accessed by getView() method. Sorry, I forgot to mention that there is only one view path (eg 'views/') defined as constant in bootstrap file. It feels correct to pass view path from action controller's constructor. But, if path doesn't changes, is there some other solution (favoring DI), so each action controller doesn't need to call parent constructor and pass the same view path all over again?

Comment: Best approach is to define a default path inside the parent abstract controller.  private $view ->path = "somepath";

Comment: @Hemaulo You are overriding the constructor inside the action controller keep this is mind. Without calling the parent::__controller, how will the view be called?

Comment: Base Controller class is part of framework and view path is defined by application. Your solution is the easiest way but then view path will be hardcoded and relative. Absolute path is preferred but each application is in different folder.

Comment: Parent constructor needs to be called only if child class defines own __construct() method. There can be controllers without dependencies and thus without constructor and in this case parent::__construct() will be called automatically.

Comment: Yes i understand. But in your example code you will have to call the parent constructor. How will in this example the view be set?