# Separation of Logging between derived and base classes with Dependency Injection C#

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection

Similar to the SO ([Dependency injection in base and derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324270/dependency-injection-in-base-and-derived-classes)), I am looking to separate logging 'category' for the base class and derived class.  I have tried variations with both answers in the SO, but not getting the desired result.

The logger being used is: `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`

**base class:**
Best effort so far was to try and cast it properly, but that didn't work.

```cs
public abstract class LifetimeEventsHostedService : IHostedService
{
  private readonly ILogger<LifetimeEventsHostedService> _logger;
  protected LifetimeEventsHostedService(ILogger logger)
  {
    _logger = (ILogger<LifetimeEventsHostedService>)logger;
  }
  public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    _logger.LogInformation("LifetimeEventsHostedService.StartAsync has been called");
  }  
}
```

**derived class:**

```cs
public class DerivedHostedService: LifetimeEventsHostedService
{
  private readonly ILogger<DerivedHostedService> _logger;

  public DerivedHostedService(ILogger<DerivedHostedService> logger) : base(logger) 
  {
    _logger = logger;
  }

  public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    await base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    _logger.LogInformation("StartAsync completed");
  }
}
```

Now the console logs show as follows:

```
info: PlayerService.Services.HostedServices.DerivedHostedService[0] // Should show as base class category
      LifetimeEventsHostedService.StartAsync has been called        // Hacky workaround to include base category in the message
info: PlayerService.Services.HostedServices.DerivedHostedService[0] // Obviously (correctly) showing correct in derived class
      StartAsync completed
info: PlayerService.Services.HostedServices.DerivedHostedService[0] // Should show as base class category
      LifetimeEventsHostedService.OnStarted has been called         // Hacky workaround to include base category in the message
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

The way I have accomplished it above works, but I would like to find a way to set the `type` (category) to the base class, separating the base class from the derived class and omit the hacky (extra detail / base class name) in the base class, rather maintaining separation of logging between the two if possible.

Comment: And yes I realize the implication and value to not separating them.

Comment: Based on your desired functionality, it would require separate instances of loggers. casting here wont work

Comment: @Nkosi hmm, that makes sense, and logically the 'hacky' way I am doing it now remains the easiest (and probably better solution, keeping a proper context in the logs given the implications of separation in the first place). Creating separate instances of the base class and injecting it rather than deriving from it, while an alternative, seems counterproductive at the same time.

Comment: why not request both loggers in the derived class? `public DerivedHostedService(ILogger<DerivedHostedService> logger, ILogger<LifetimeEventsHostedService> baseLogger) : base(baseLogger)`

Comment: @qujck you know, I did try that, but it was giving me a Roslyn warning in the IDE so I abandoned it before *actually* trying it.  No compiler warnings though when I just tested it, and does in fact provide the results I was looking for.  Please feel free to provide as an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: The reason why you are even able to cast the `ILogger<Derived>` to an `ILogger<Base>` is because `ILogger<T>` is defined as covariant `ILogger<out T>`. However, making `ILogger<T>` covariant is a very strange design decision because casting it will never have the desired result (as your code demonstrates). I would even argue that making `ILogger<T>` covariant is a design flaw; Microsoft shouldn't have made `ILogger<T>` covariant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could request both loggers in the derived class:

```
public DerivedHostedService(
    ILogger<DerivedHostedService> logger, 
    ILogger<LifetimeEventsHostedService> baseLogger) : base(baseLogger)
{}
```

Comment: Thanks, as noted above in the comments, I did start down this path (and abandoned it prematurely), but the IDE will show this as a warning (sorry not Roslyn, this may be a Rider specific warning or possibly other IDE's), but can be disabled.

**WARNING** (to others): This is not best practice, and probably should be avoided unless you have very specific reasons for separating the two.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another option if you end up needing multiple services in your base class but don't want every derived class to have to call them all out. I personally would avoid it, but it would probably bypass the warning you're getting although I personally think you have "very specific reasons for separating the two" anyway.

```
   public DerivedHostedService(
        ILogger<DerivedHostedService> logger, 
        IServiceProvider services) : base(services)
    {}

    public BaseHostedService(
        IServiceProvider services)
    {

      var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<BaseHostedService>>();

      // etc

    }
```

Comment: Good alternative, kinda breaks DI of course, and can cause some security concerns, but I like it as a hacky alternative.

Comment: I wouldn't say it breaks DI at all since you'll always be able to inject the service provider.